# Error when running "telescope:prune": ""telescope_entries_tags" does not have a replica identity and publishes deletes"

Tags: php, laravel

When I try running the command `php artisan telescope:prune --hours=240`, I get the following error:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[55000]: Object not in prerequisite state: 7 ERROR:  cannot delete from table "telescope_entries_tags" because it does not have a replica identity and publishes deletes
HINT:  To enable deleting from the table, set REPLICA IDENTITY using ALTER TABLE.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DELETE FROM ONLY "api"."telescope_entries_tags" WHERE $1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "entry_uuid"" (SQL: delete from "telescope_entries" where "ctid" in (select "telescope_entries"."ctid" from "telescope_entries" where "created_at" < 2023-04-08 07:33:36 limit 1000))

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712
```